# c++ Headers with the same class name

Tags: c++, header

I am an engineering student and not a very strong programmer. One of my assignments includes creating a VR program using openGL. I've been given a template (that I really don't want to re-write) that uses the [gmtl](http://ggt.sourceforge.net/) headers extensively. The assignment requires implementing some [sixense](http://sixense.com/developers) position tracker hardware in the simulation, however, the headers for the sixense hardware and gmtl both have a number of classes (Plane, Line, etc.) with the same names. Is there anything I can do to use both that doesn't involve going through lots of code and renaming things?

Comment: aren't they defined in different namespaces?

Comment: Are they in namespaces? If so, it should be okay.

Comment: gmtl is definitely in a `gmtl` namespace.

Comment: If the headers for both of these are present in 2 separate directories under a common parent dir - eg. `myincludefiles/gtml/` and `myincludefiles/sixense`, you can use relative include paths which contain the `gtml/` or `sixense/` prefix whenever you include the headers.

Comment: the code is using namespace gmtl. The sixense headers are not in their own folder and don't have a namespace defined as far as I know and I am getting an error. If I place them in their own directory and use the relative paths should that fix things? I wish I had the time to understand this better.

Comment: What about libraries? Can they also be placed in the sub directory?

Comment: I might be asking the wrong thing. Here is the exact error I'm getting:'c:\users\kyle\desktop\collision\collision\sixense\sixense_math.hpp(206): error C2990: 'gmtl::Plane' : non-class template has already been declared as a class template
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\gmtl\plane.h(37) : see declaration of 'gmtl::Plane''

Comment: What is the code on and around `line 206` of `sixense_math.hpp`? Is that something you've written?

Answer (score 2):

As commenters have stated, they are in different namespaces so you should be fine, as long as you fully qualify your namespaces, which is good practice too:

```
namespace foo { int value; }
namespace bar { int value; }

int main()
{
    foo::value = 1;
    bar::value = 2;
    return 0;
}
```

You only run into trouble if you use `using namespace` recklessly:

```
namespace foo { int value; }
namespace bar { int value; }

using namespace foo;
using namespace bar;

int main()
{
    value = 1; // which value is this???
    return 0;
}
```

In practice, if you have well-structured, modular code, it will be very rare to have to use two classes with the same name in the same source file, and usually the classes are doing the same thing, which means you can isolate the verbose, fully-qualified type names in a "conversion" source file, and continue to use `using namespace` in your other source files.

Comment: Yes. I think I understand this. Is it reasonable to just enclose all the code in the sixense header files in a namespace?

Comment: @kballing No, don't take someone's code and wrap it in `namespace foo` -- that is a bad idea.  Remove the `using namespace gmtl` from your code, everywhere.  Don't try to stick someones' code in a `namespace` they didn't put it in themselves.  Never `#include` a file within a `namespace blah {` ... `}` block.  (well, naturally not never, but never is the easiest approximation)